# Removing pages from search engine results

Tags: seo

Hey everyone, I'm a bit new to SEO. I built a one page website that initially utilized several pages (but are now removed), and it looks as if Google has indexed those so that they show up as search results. Is there any way to remove those from the search results? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google has a page](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=164734&&hl=en) describing how to remove your site from their results.

Answer (score 0):

Use a robots.txt file:
[Robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

example robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /url1.html
Disallow: /url2.html
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Robots exclusion rules.  This site details it : http://www.robotstxt.org/

Comment: Robots.txt prevents *crawling*, not necessarily *indexing* (there is a difference).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your server/application is sending correct 404 HTTP header on requests of non existing pages and wait.